# How to change Django default date format

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I want to change the default Django date format from year-day-month to day-month-year format

I tried adding DATE_INPUT_FORMATS=[‘%d.%m.%Y] in settings.Py file but the changes still doesn’t reflect while using the form

here is my form.py file code

```
class PersonalDetailForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=PersonalDetail
        fields='__all__'
```

here is the views:

```
def regForm(request):

    form = PersonalDetailForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = PersonalDetailForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # return redirect('/')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('staff:staffhome'))

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'ems/regform.html', context)
```

here is the model

```
class PersonalDetail(models.Model):
    staff_no = models.IntegerField()
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    middlename = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=300)
    phone_number = models.IntegerField()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change default input format in your form, you should pass `DateInput` widget to your field and also `input_formats` kwarg. For example:

```py
from django import forms

class PersonalDetailForm(forms.Form):
    date_of_birth = forms.DateField(
        widget=forms.DateInput(format='%d.%m.%Y'),
        input_formats=['%d.%m.%Y']
    )
```

Or in case with the `ModelForm`

```py
from django import forms
from .models import PersonalDetail

class PersonalDetailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    date_of_birth = forms.DateField(
        widget=forms.DateInput(format='%d.%m.%Y'),
        input_formats=['%d.%m.%Y']
    )

    class Meta:
        model = PersonalDetail
        fields = '__all__'
```

You can read more about DateField in here: [Django DateField in forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#datefield)

And here about date formating in general [Django date format](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date)

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the date format in by creating a field and mentioning inline `widget` so:

```py
from django import forms
from .models import PersonalDetail

class PersonalDetailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    date_of_birth = forms.DateField(
        widget=forms.DateInput(format='%d-%m-%Y'),
        input_formats=['%d-%m-%Y']
    )

    class Meta:
        model = PersonalDetail
        fields = '__all__'
```